# How to reformat code for CAPL language in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, capl

When I write code for CAPL language but format of souce code not beauty, So I want to find the way to reformat code in vs code.

I was try with prettier but It not operation

Comment: if there is no formatter for CAPL in the Marketplace you can always write one yourself

Comment: You could simply use the C formatter. The syntax is close enough.

Comment: using what formatter?

Comment: if there is no formatter for CAPL in the Marketplace you can always write one yourself – 
rioV8
 Now, I don't know the way to write it. Can you provide something or a link as a tutorial to help me implement it?